# Hide absolute positioned div on hover

Tags: css, position, hide

I have this html:

```
<div class="caption">
    <h2><a href="single-image.html">Sun Flower</a></h2>
    <p class="meta-info-font">I took this photo at some bla bla bla.. and some other stuff.</p>
</div>
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(20,19,19,0.94);
    display: none;
}

.caption:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `.caption { display: block; } .caption:hover { display: none; }` Simply your div is hidden by default...

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski post that as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 3):

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(20,19,19,0.94);
    display: block; /* HERE */
}

.caption:hover {
    display: none; /* HERE */
}
```

Simply your div was hidden by default.

Comment: Doesn't hide in IE. `:hover` is intented only for anchors in IE. There is some behaviour in Firefox too, but.. seems working

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
.caption {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgba(20,19,19,0.94);
        display: block;
    }

    .caption:hover {
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(20,19,19,0.94);
    display: block;
}

.caption:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Your div must be display:block, so when you hover on it, it can be display:none

Answer (score 0):

I tried checking the CSS in chrome and FireFox and it does not seem to be cross browser compatible. Why don't you write up some javascript yo hide it on hover..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RBmvV/)